# Run functions/hooks automatically when a specific FILE is opened

Tags: hooks, find-file

I'd like to run a function/set of functions when I open a specific file.
Just like file type hooks, but for a specific file.

For instance, when I open foo.bar, I'd like some functions to run.

Maybe those functions are specified on my init.el or in the file itself; I don't mind either.

Is there some built in functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in a `find-file-hook` function. Just have the function test for your file, and if the file to visit is different then do nothing.

`C-h v find-file-hook` tells us:

> `find-file-hook` is a variable defined in `files.el`.
>
> Its value is
>
> `(global-eldoc-mode-check-buffers global-font-lock-mode-check-buffers epa-file-find-file-hook vc-refresh-state)`
>
> Original value was `nil`
>
> List of functions to be **called after a buffer is loaded from a file**.
>
> The buffer’s local variables (if any) will have been processed before the
> functions are called.  This includes directory-local variables, if any,
> for the file’s directory.

The hook is run with the buffer with the visited file current, so `(buffer-file-name)` should give you the name of the file.

Comment: Hello Drew, thanks for the answer. How should I obtain the file name on the function that I'm gonna use as a hook? buffer-file-name?

Comment: Yes. I updated the answer with that info.